# Why does a system hang after it has been running for over 12 hours?

Tags: windows, memory, performance, freeze, uptime

After my SSD failed, the only other option was to revert to a standard hard drive.  Since then, I've noticed that the system cannot endure more than 12 hours before experiencing intermittent lockups which can elapse between 1 - 5 minutes.  It doesn't outright crash or shutdown, it just simply locks up for a short period of time.  While it probably doesn't help having 80% of system RAM in use, I'm still curious of what causes this issue and of what can be done to remedy the system of it.  Oh, and I'm using Windows 7 x64 as a primary OS (a clean install).

Comment: If the HDD is active during that time, the system is probably busy swapping. Try running ProcExp to diagnose it. Other issues may include overheating of CPU or GPU. Does the entire system hang, or just the specific application?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of possibilities:

- since this is a fresh install of windows, you might not have the correct and/or up-to-date drivers for some piece of hardware that goes into a wait-state periodically; or
- since this is a fresh install of windows, there's a higher probability that your hardware is broken in some way.

Since you mention waits of 1-5 minutes, I'd check the event log for indications of hard disk timeouts.  If you replaced the dead SSD with a new one, then this might mean the motherboard I/O controller is dying.  If you replaced the dead SSD with an old disk then this might mean the old disk is dying, but for my money I'd guess motherboard.

Comment: It's happened before, and something I've generally observed with HDDs.  When using an SSD however, speed increases were prominent and the system could endure around 48 hours before experiencing this trouble.  However, I will try a new motherboard - it has aged quite a bit now.  All system drivers are up-to-date too, and diagnostics don't report any trouble with the HDD itself.  Someone once mentioned that it might be something to do with the way Windows handles its page file and suggested switching to Windows Server 2008 or Linux, albeit I'm unsure of what it is to determine the best option.

Comment: @user784446 - It sounds like you have bad hardware.  Since this isn't a new issue and you know the cause ( the motherboard ) Switching your operating system won't solve anything.

Comment: Apologies, but I didn't state that the motherboard is faulty but rather that it has aged quite a bit (well, it's actually just short of 3 years).